# Deploying an application that uses an Open AI key

Tags: python, github, streamlit, openai-api

I want to deploy my Streamlit app in Streamlit's cloud service but it requires the repo to be public on GitHub, which Open AI doesn't allow. Is there any way to bypass this? I currently don't know any other method of deploying.

I tried keeping it private and running it on Streamlit anyway, but Streamlit can't work with that. I tried making it public, but then my key was invalidated.

Comment: Whatever you do, don’t make your key public.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better answered by Streamlit's support team.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy apps without making the secret keys public. For this purpose, use [Secrets Management](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management). As stated inside the provided documentation, do:

1. Go to http://share.streamlit.io/ and click "New app" to deploy a new app with secrets.
2. Click "Advanced settings..."
3. You will see a modal appear with an input box for your secrets.

   [image]
4. Provide your secrets in the "Secrets" field using TOML format. For example:

   ```ini
   # Everything in this section will be available as an environment variable
   openai_secret_key = "ABCDEF-1234-GHIJKL"
   ```

Then, to use secrets in your app, you can use `st.secrets`. In your case, it would look like this:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.write("Secret Key", st.secrets["openai_secret_key"])

# And the root-level secrets are also accessible as environment variables:

import os

st.write(
    "Has environment variables been set:",
    os.environ["openai_secret_key"] == st.secrets["openai_secret_key"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streamlit's built in secrets.toml file - please see here for [official docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management).  Here you store secret keys that are not tracked within your .gitignore file.  This way, you can use open ai API keys without exposing these sensitive keys to a github repository.  Please see below for working example.

```
#root_directory/.streamlit/secrets.toml
open_ai_key='type_your_key_here'
open_ai_secret='type_your_secret_here'



#.gitignore
*.toml


#root_directory/pages/sample_page.py
import streamlit as st
open_ai_key = st.secrets['open_ai_key']
```

You will have to manually fill out this secrets.toml file whenever cloning your repository, on a cloud server for example, which will ensure your secret keys are kept safe.